# Same Charge or Same Potential?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, potential, equilibrium

I was studying about sharing of charge between two charged conductors when I came across this statement -

> When two conductors are joined together through a conducting wire, charge begins to flow from one conductor to another till both have the *same potential*.

I always thought that charges flow from one point to another until they are able to neutralize the charges at the other point. I felt this was obvious.

But the above statement caused me to reconsider things. Can you tell me why do charges flow till they have same potential? (why not same charge)

Comment: If there were a difference in electric potential between two conductors that would mean there is an electric field between them and charges move under the influence of electric fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I always thought that charges flow from one point to another until they are able to neutralize the charges at the other point. I felt this was obvious.

What if that other point is already neutral? For example if you connect a neutral (uncharged) metal piece to a negatively charged metal piece. Will no charges move to the neutral piece, since there is no net charge to neutralize here? Of course it will - the charge will spread out as much as it can. Until not the charge, but the *potential* at any point is the same.

Before connection, there are excess charges (electrons) caught at the charged piece. These are pushing each other as far away as possible - they all repel. They can't move beyond the objects surface, though, because the air is not conducting. But when the other neutral but conducting object is connected, they can move over there. They are *pushed* over there due to the repulsion of the others - and there is no (or at least a smaller) repulsion from the neutral piece. The push is stronger *towards* the neutral piece than *away* from it. And so, the move.

**This is potential**. That charges are pushed away from a point is what we call *a potential* (potential energy per charge). When there is a **potential difference between two points**, it means that the charge is being pushed more **towards** than **away** from a point. And so, the charge will move if it can. And it can when there is a connection between the two points.

It will not want to move if there is no potential difference. In the same way, a ball on a shelf will not want to move sideways, since this is a point of equal (gravitational) potential. It will only want to move downwards, towards a *decrease* in potential.

Indeed, the motion of charges is caused by the amounts of charge present, but we are not talking about charge being neutralized. Rather about electric forces being balanced - in other words, about *electric potentials* being balanced.

Comment: Sir, You are brilliant. You gave me an excellent intuitive idea of potential. Based on what I understood, in this image (https://imgur.com/zQ41Wtx), charges move from A to B as they are being pushed more towards B than towards A?

Answer (score 1):

Charges flow in response to electric fields. Electric fields are given by the rate of change of potential. Consequently, at the point when there are no electric fields, there is not change in potential and so the potential must be the same at all the point you are considering. Therefore, when you connect two capacitors current will flow until both have the same potential.

Now charges do produce electric fields and so, if there are no other fields present, charges will flow until the charge everywhere is neutralised, at which point the potential everywhere will be the same. If, however, there are other fields present, for example in a circuit they may be produced by the battery, this will not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Think of two containers having two different levels of water. Connecting the both, there will be flow of water from high level to low level irrespective of the volume if water. Same happens for charges. Van de Graff generator works on this principle too.